# onActivityForResult doesn't get called in Android plugin for Unity application

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have an Android plugin (aar) that is generated and included in a Unity project. I can call functions in the plugin and functions in the plugin can call functions in the Unity project. However, when I call a function in the plugin to uninstall an application using "startActivityForResult", the uninstall action runs but the "onActivityResult" never triggers after the uninstall operation is complete. I've seen many stack overflow questions regarding onActivityForResult not getting triggered but nothing has helped. I'm assuming it has something to do with the activity the intent is being started at not aligning with where the onActivityForResult is being overridden at, but I'm not sure.

Here's my code:

```
    package com.unity3d.player;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.app.Activity;

    public class UnityInstallPermissions extends Activity{
       
        public static int UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

        public static void UninstallApp(String packageName)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
            UnityPlayer.currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == UNINSTALL_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("EventSystem","UninstallResult","SUCCESS");
                } else  {
                    UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("EventSystem","UninstallResult","CANCELED");
                }
            }
            finish();
        }
    }
```